# Airplane accidents that happen during take off and landing

Tags: aircraft-performance, landing, takeoff, accidents, accident-investigation

I have just seen some documentary about Munich Air Disaster in 1958. I found that the real reason behind this disaster is related to the aircraft performance with the thick snow runway during take off. So could you help me to find some more similar accidents that happens due to the aircraft bad performance, espically in take off or descent/landing ? It's my pleasure to see yours answers. My english writing skill is quite bad so pardon me if I made any mistake ! Thanks for reading !

Comment: Some [on SKYbrary](https://skybrary.aero/articles/accident-and-serious-incident-reports-re).

Comment: If you're looking for documentaries, there's an entire TV series called Mayday/Air Disasters.

Comment: Are you asking about accidents caused by snow that reduced the aircraft's performance? Your question seems very broad and I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the accident you mentioned was not bad performance of the plane, but the effect the thick snow on the runway had on the plane. Basically a pilot error, or bad info given to the pilot. Pilot in command is responsible for assuring the conditions are such that the plane can be safely operated. PIC either failed to do so, or was given false information about the condition of the runway.

Some search terms that would give you accidents of a similar type are *icing*, *de-ice / de-icing*, *runway contamination*, *insufficient performance*, *adverse weather*, *downpour*, and the most obvious *slush* and *snow storm*.

Comment: Similar accident in 2001 in Bremerhaven, Germany: https://www.bfu-web.de/DE/Publikationen/Untersuchungsberichte/2001/Bericht_3X286-0.01.pdf?__blob=publicationFile

Answer (score 1):

A couple of useful, searchable, resources are [AVHerald](https://avherald.com/) and the https://www.ntsb.gov/Pages/AviationQuery.aspx.  The problem you'll have is working out a query that will only return the sort of answer you want since accident reports mention take-off and landing, even when they haven't always occurred.